# Regular Expression negation not working correctly

Tags: java, regex, negation

I am using the following regular expression:

```
^[^^DD(|    ]
```

With this data:

```
jfklajf
^DD
     hjhkjk
DIOL(.D1)
```

The expression correctly identifies the first line (jfkl...), but fails to identify the last line (DIOL...).  I need to identify both lines as not matching the pattern `^DD(` at the start of the line.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: In which programming language are you trying to accomplish this? Almosty certainly `[^^DD]` is not what you want as it says *neither ^ nor D*.

Comment: I am working in Java.  I need to identify lines which do not begin with either ^DD( or 4 spaces

Comment: Thats perfect, thanks for the assistance

Answer (score 4):

As per your comment you could use a neg. lookahead in combination with anchors:

```
^(?!\^DD|[ ]{4}).+
```

---

Broken down, this says:

```
^          # match start of the line
(?!        # neg. lookahead
    \^DD   # neither ^DD
    |      # nor
    [ ]{4} # four spaces
)
.+         # omit empty lines
```

---

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/In13uY/1/). Note that you need to double escape backslashes in `Java`.

Comment: If the answer helped you, please consider upvoting and or accepting it.

Answer (score 1):

You need a negative lookahead. Something like this

```
^(?!((\^DD)|(    )))
```

See https://regexr.com/3ke44

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps:

```
(?!^\^DD|^\s+)^.+$
```

See the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/nrOe4g/1)

Yours is currently attempting to match any character in this list:

`D`, , `(`, `|`

Using a group construct instead of the character list (square brackets), you'll have more luck

Answer (score 0):

Your regex is saying : as sentence not starting with ^, D, (, | or space.

[] construct is a character class meaning it will match any *one* character from the class, starting the class with ^ negates it and means any *one* character not in the class.

As stated in the others answers you should look for a negative lookahead or if you like complexity and I understand your try well:

```
^([^^][^D]{2}[^(]|[^ ]{4})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
^((?![^DD|\s{4}]).)
```

Explanation

```
^...Start of the line
((?!Expression).)...not matching
[^DD|\s{4}]...Pattern 1 (^DD) or Pattern 2 (\s{4})
\s{4}...whitespaces 4 times
```

Comment: Nope - this will even reject lines starting with a single `D` which is not what the OP wants.